# Can I mix grouped and full-width cells in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've been given a design for a view which mostly uses grouped table cells, but every so often has a full-width cell for particularly important calls to action.  Can I mix grouped and full-width cells in a UITableView?  If so, how?

Comment: I am not very clear what exactly you are trying to achieve here. You certainly cannot mix up both of the things in a TableView.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it natively, but you can try to simulate it using full-width cells and putting a background image with rounded corner in cell content.